# Understanding an implicit loop in SAS data step

Tags: sas

I am trying this sample SAS program to understand the DATA step:

```
DATA WITHOUT_1;
PUT "Before the INPUT statement:  " _ALL_;

INPUT X @@;
PUT "After the INPUT statement:   " _ALL_ /;
DATALINES;
1 2 . 3
;
```

I did not specify any loops in the program, but how come the PUT statements are logged for each data line?

Where is the implicit loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DATA step itself is an implicit loop.

Note that when you run your code the log listing includes the loop counter, `_N_`.

Your step iterates 5 times because on the 5th iteration, there is no more data to read and it stops:

```
1    DATA WITHOUT_1;
2    PUT "Before the INPUT statement:  " _ALL_;
3
4    INPUT X @@;
5    PUT "After the INPUT statement:   " _ALL_ /;
6    DATALINES;

Before the INPUT statement:  X=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
After the INPUT statement:   X=1 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1

Before the INPUT statement:  X=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=2
After the INPUT statement:   X=2 _ERROR_=0 _N_=2

Before the INPUT statement:  X=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=3
After the INPUT statement:   X=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=3

Before the INPUT statement:  X=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=4
After the INPUT statement:   X=3 _ERROR_=0 _N_=4

Before the INPUT statement:  X=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=5
NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a line.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WITHOUT_1 has 4 observations and 1 variables.

8    ;
```

Note it is also possible  (and sometimes useful) to replace the implicit loop with an explicit loop, e.g.:

```
DATA WITHOUT_1;
  do i=1 to 4;
    PUT "Before the INPUT statement:  " _ALL_;
    INPUT X @@;
    PUT "After the INPUT statement:   " _ALL_ /;
  end;
  stop;
DATALINES;
1 2 . 3
;
```